# Unable to distribute app with the EnterPrise account

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I have developed an iOS 8 app. I have a strange issue that By using the AdHoc Profile I am able to share the app to the clients where as If I use the EnterPrise account unable to run it.It opens and immediately closed down.

Any ideas or suggestions could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1)Please check the Device date.
2)Please ZIP the IPA and check the payload if your UDID exits or not.
3)Please check the Certificate expired or not.

Comment: I have checked everything. All are correct the issue is With the Swift . Most of the developers are facing issues when using the Swift